# Using pandas' read_hdf to load data on Google Drive fails with ValueError

Tags: pandas, google-colaboratory

I have uploaded a HDF file to Google Drive and wish to load it in Colab. The file was created from a dataframe with `DataFrame.to_hdf()` and it can be loaded successfully locally with `pd.read_hdf()`. However, when I try to mount my Google Drive and read the data in Colab, it fails with a `ValueError`.

Here is the code I am using to read the data:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
data = pd.read_hdf('/content/drive/My Drive/Ryhmäytyminen/data/data.h5', 'students')
```

And this is the full error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-cfe913c26e60> in <module>()
----> 1 data = pd.read_hdf('/content/drive/My Drive/Ryhmäytyminen/data/data.h5', 'students')

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tables/vlarray.py in read(self, start, stop, step)
    819             listarr = []
    820         else:
--> 821             listarr = self._read_array(start, stop, step)
    822 
    823         atom = self.atom

tables/hdf5extension.pyx in tables.hdf5extension.VLArray._read_array()

ValueError: cannot set WRITEABLE flag to True of this array
```

Reading some JSON data was successful, so the problem probably is not with mounting. Any ideas what is wrong or how to debug this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Try navigating to the directory that you store your HDF file first:

```
cd /content/drive/My Drive/Ryhmäytyminen/data
```

From here you should be able to load the HDF file directly:

```
data = pd.read_hdf('data.h5', 'students')
```